# Microservices and database changes

Tags: database, microservices

We have microservices and DDL scripts for database as resources in jar file, which are deployed on start microservice using liquibase/flyway.
It looks Ok for DDL.

What to do with DML?
We should build new jar file with DML scripts and then redeploy microservice?
Or will be better to have separate deployments for database and microservices?

How to do export/import data between environments (dev,sit,uat,etc)?

If microservice support CRUD operations, can we use microservice for export/import data?
I.e. on dev environment we do setup data, then do export into json, and import on uat using microservice and json.

Answer (score 0):

Oleg, good question. I suggest separating Database deployment from app deployment and adopting a GitOps strategy (CD) for both.

The pipeline will deploy DB (applying DDL), and you will control the flow -- this is what is said as DataOps practice.
https://www.truedataops.org

This separation between application and database help you with manutenability aspects (one key objective of Microservices Architecture).

About the migration of Data from environments, there are many tools that help this kind of job very efficiently, and each datastore has one usually.

For example, Oracle GoldenGate can help this process.
https://www.oracle.com/integration/goldengate/

But I wonder why you are migrating data from environments that pertain to different phases of your product life cycle (dev data usually is non-productive data, also it is not a best practice to have production data in Dev stages -- security/protection concerns).